# How to change how links appear (hide anchor tags and ".html") on CSS or htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, hide, anchor

I have some links and I want them to be shown under the same name on the browser.
For example www.link.com/index.htm or www.link.com/#anchor to be shown as www.link.com

I have tried that using css by putting that:

```
 link.address.href = link.address.href.replace(/#.*/,'')
```

and

```
link.address.href = link.address.href.replace(/i.*/,'')
```

but it doesn't work. I cannot find the possible ways to do that. I can think of :

CSS way which is the easiest for me, JS but I am not that literate in this
and htaccess file creation. Although I have to be careful because I am not sure which server I am going to use. Which one is the best?

What am I doing wrong with the css modification above?

Answer (score 0):

```
link.address.href = link.address.href.replace(/#.*/,'')
```

Is this CSS? :P

For the anchor thing... You have a www.link.com/#anchor and you want to make it www.link.com/ 
In PHP, it would be easy using this one:

```
$link = strstr($link, '#', true);
```

If your file is in PHP it should work. I am still trying to find the way to do it without using JS for HTML though. Also, I have never been into the .htaccess thing so I cannot answer your second question. I would be interested to know though. Hope the php version helps you.